# Почему "Ему чужда душа моя", а не наоборот?

Tags: грамотная-речь, пушкин

В отповеди Онегина на письмо Татьяны есть слова:

```
Но я не создан для блаженства;
Ему чужда душа моя; . . .
```

Почему Пушкин написал "Ему чужда душа моя"? Ведь сейчас мы бы сказали
"Ей (моей душе) чуждо блаженство" (как мы сказали бы "Мне чуждо
веселье").

Он это специально перевернул? Или с тех пор нормы языка изменились?

PS. Интересно / странно, что А. Минкин в своей серии статей "Немой Онегин" не остановился на этом (хотя и обсуждает там огромное множество других интересных вещей).

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос...
Попробую ответить содержательно, хотя тут есть над чем подумать куда более достойным пушкинистам.

Во-первых, никакие нормы в этой части не менялись. Тут же отношения объекта-субъекта, закрепленные грамматикой. Даже не представляю, что должно измениться, чтобы в той же грамматике объект и субъект поменялись местами в смысловом отношении. Но это так, для разгону.

В-вторых. Я не очень согласен с уже данными ответами. Пушкин - это же Пушкин, ну какие у него могут быть инверсии ради инверсии? Или, того хуже, ради потребностей рифмы и размера?

Ну и главное. Без контекста обсуждать тут построение фразы бессмысленно. Но из меня, как сказал, пушкинист аховый, вынужден ограничиться лишь тем, что на поверхности.
Я полагаю, что определяющий контекст тут в том, что Онегин лукавит в своем ответе, не желая назвать прямо настоящую причину - отсутствие истинных чувств к Татьяне по причине того, что она ему не ровня.

В результате он и строит свое объяснение в пасcиве: мол я не очень-то и виноват, это обстоятельства такие, не я, Онегин, не принимаю блаженства, а оно, блаженство, меня к себе не берет. Тем самым Онегин перекрывает выход наружу своих чувств вообще... Я не хозяин своим чувствам - я не могу вас полюбить.

Можно сравнить со стилем письма Онегина уже замужней Татьяне в восьмой главе. Вот тут и искренность и чувства рекой... И, разумеется, автор письма предстает активным, деятельным хозяином своих чувств. И оправдывается за свою холодность. ("В вас искру нежности заметя, **Я** ей поверить не посмел..."

Answer (score 2):

Это выражение, хотя и выбрано здесь из потребностей рифмы и ритма стиха, вполне может опираться на представление о том, что какое-либо ощущение, чувство (надежда, уверенность и т. п.) способно "[поселиться в душе](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B2+%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5)".
Если же такая возможность отрицается, т. е. это нечто ни в коем случае в душе не "поселится", это значит, что **душа** никогда не станет для него пристанищем, "домом" - она останется *чужой* для этого чувства (здесь: *блаженства*), **чуждой ему**.

Comment: Это объяснение мне кажется наиболее правдоподобным / возможным. Я о нем тоже уже думал. Единственный его недостаток: ведь это говорит Онегин, который поэтом не являлся. И поэтому Пушкин не должен был бы вкладывать в его уста выражения, свойственные лишь поэтическим душам. Хотя, как известно из предыдущего текста "Онегина", он был образован в литературном смысле и мог бы "притворяться".

Comment: Насчет "из потребностей рифмы и ритма стиха" я не согласен. Пушкин очень бережно и тщательно относился к своим текстам, переписывал и отшлифовывал их по многу раз. И в отсутствии мастерства / умения рифмовать его тоже не заподозришь.

Answer (score 2):

**Это инверсия, только не языковая, а художественная,** то есть оригинальный способ изображения человека и его  душевного состояния. Обычно мы чувства относим к человеку, а здесь всё наоборот.

Этот прием задан уже в первой строке: ***я не создан*** для блаженства.

Блаженство мыслится как отвлеченная самостоятельная категория, **которая выбирает для себя среду обитания**. И вот мятежная душа поэта — это не лучшее пристанище для спокойствия, счастья, удовольствия, наслаждения, то есть тех эмоций, с которыми мы связываем это состояние.

И еще. Я не думаю, что **конкретное содержание** как-то влияет на форму выражения. Эти слова говорит Онегин, который при этом лукавит, но точно так же мог сказать о себе, к примеру, сам Пушкин, причем совершенно искренне и по другому поводу. Это всего лишь оборот речи — тогда, вероятно,  любили выражаться так фигурально.